# What URL should I use with Expo to redirect to a published app?

Tags: redirect, expo

I am performing some OAuth autentication and I need to redirect from the Expo WebBrowser back to my application. I can do it with the development URL *exp://some-code.name.app-name.exp.direct/+/redirect* as shown in the example project https://github.com/expo/auth0-example. However, I am not sure what URL to use with the published application. Something like *https://exp.host/@name/app-name/+/redirect* or *exp://exp.host/@name/app-name/+/redirect* or something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

why you don't just use

```
 redirectUri = `${Expo.Constants.linkingUri}/redirect`
```